# Cross-platform way to get all files in directory in C++ besides boost

Tags: c++, directory, cross-platform

Is there other cross-platform way except using Boost to get all files in directory? 
opendir/readdir seems not working under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cross-platform framework called [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29). An example solution to your problem:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QListWidget window;

    QDir dir("/");
    QStringList list = dir.entryList();

    window.addItems(list);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This is overkill. QT is a GUI framework and comes with lots of dependencies that won't be used.